# Update DataFrame using a slice of a MultiIndex (many rows) with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `MultiIndex` of dimensions `I, M` and would like for one `i \in I` to update all `M` rows at the same time.

Here is my data frame:

```
>>> result.head(n=10)
Out[9]: 
         FINLWT21
i INCAGG         
0 1           NaN
  7           NaN
  9           NaN
  5           NaN
  3           NaN
1 1           NaN
  7           NaN
  9           NaN
  5           NaN
  3           NaN
```

Here is what I would like to fill in:

```
sample.groupby(field).sum()
            FINLWT21
INCAGG              
1        8800809.719
3        9951002.611
5        9747721.721
7        7683066.990
9       11091861.692
```

I thought the right command would be `result.loc[i] = sample.groupby(field).sum()`. However, here is the contents of `result` afterwards:

```
>>> result.loc[i]
Out[11]: 
       FINLWT21
INCAGG         
1           NaN
7           NaN
9           NaN
5           NaN
3           NaN
```

How can I update all the "inner index" at the same time?

Comment: your example is a bit incomplete - what are `sample` and `field`?  However, if I've understood correctly, you might have to use `pd.merge` with `reset_index`, i.e. switch to single-indexing to do the merge.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `pd.IndexSlice`.  It returns an object that can be used in sclicing with `loc`.

#### Solution

```
result.sort_index();
slc = pd.IndexSlice[i, :]
result.loc[slc, :] = sample.groupby(field).sum()
```

#### Explanation

`result.sort_index();` -> `pd.IndexSclice` requires the index be sorted.

`slc = pd.IndexSclice[i, :]` -> syntax to create a generic slicer to get ith group of 1st level for a `pd.MultiIndex` with 2 levels.

'result.loc[slc, :] = ` -> use the slice

#### Demonstration

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


result = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['FINLWT21'],
                      index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0, 1], [1, 7, 9, 5, 3]]))

result.sort_index(inplace=True);
slc = pd.IndexSlice[0, :]

result.loc[slc, :] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print result

    FINLWT21
0 1        1
  3        2
  5        3
  7        4
  9        5
1 1      NaN
  3      NaN
  5      NaN
  7      NaN
  9      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I have which might be what you are looking for:

```
def _assign_multi_index(dest, k, v, inplace=True, bool_nan=False):
    """
    assigns v to dest[k] inplace, doing a "sensible" multi-index alignment, raising
    a ValueError if no alignment is achieved.
    I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, or a reason not to do it
    the way it's currently written.
    """
    if not inplace:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    if k in dest:
        warn("key '{}' already exists, continue with caution!".format(k))
    v_names = v.index.names
    dest_names = dest.index.names
    if all(n in dest_names for n in v_names):
        if len(v_names) < len(dest_names): 
            # if need be, drop some index levels temporarily in dest
            dropped_names = [n for n in dest_names if n not in v_names]
            dest.reset_index(dropped_names, inplace=True)
        v.index = v.index.reorder_levels([n for n in dest_names if n in v_names]) # just to be safe
    else:
        raise ValueError("index levels do not match dest.")

    dest[k] = v

    # restore the original index levels if need be
    if dest.index.names != dest_names:
        dest.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dest.set_index(dest_names, inplace=True)

    if bool_nan != np.nan and v.dtype.name == 'bool' and dest[k].dtype.name != 'bool':
        # this happens when nans had to be inserted, let's convert nans
        dest_k = dest[k].copy()
        dest_k[pd.isnull(dest_k)] = bool_nan 
        dest[k] = dest_k.astype(bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the probably best way is to add an index to the right data set. The following works as expected:

```
    data = sample.groupby(field).sum()
    data['index'] = i

    result.loc[i] = data.reset_index().set_index(['index', field])
```